# Mapstruct does not create constructors with lombok

Tags: spring, mapstruct

In my project, I am using Lombok and mapstruct.

Here is my entity.

**Wallet**

```
package com.coin.cointracker.entity;

import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Wallet {
    //Library
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @NonNull
    private Long id;

    @NonNull
    private double InitialHolding;

    @NonNull
    private String currency;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "wallet", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Set<Transaction> transactions = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Here is DTO, **WalletResponse**

```
    import lombok.*;

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class WalletResponse {

    private Long id;

    private double InitialHolding;

    private String currency;
}
```

**WalletMapper**

```
import com.coin.cointracker.dto.response.WalletResponse;
import com.coin.cointracker.entity.Wallet;
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;

import java.util.Optional;

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface WalletMapper {
    WalletMapper map = Mappers.getMapper(WalletMapper.class);

    //TODO: Is it problem to have Optional as type for parameter?
    WalletResponse walletToWalletResponse(Optional<Wallet> wallet);

    //Wallet walletRequestToWallet(WalletRequest walletRequest);
}
```

And lastly my **pom.xml**:

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.4.1.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
        <org.projectlombok.version>1.18.16</org.projectlombok.version>
        <lombok-mapstruct-binding.version>0.2.0</lombok-mapstruct-binding.version>
</properties>
...
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok-mapstruct-binding.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

...
...
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source> <!-- depending on your project -->
                    <target>1.8</target> <!-- depending on your project -->
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.3.0.Beta2</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>1.18.4</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Repositories and services works fine. Repository successfully get data from db and services successfully calls mapper with data in database. But Mapper can not maps Wallet to WalletResponse.It results as this:

```
    {
"id":null,
"InitialHolding":0.00,
"currency":null
}
```

Where did I make mistake?

**EDIT** : Here is generated WalletMapperImpl

```
    package com.coin.cointracker.mapper;

import com.coin.cointracker.dto.response.WalletResponse;
import com.coin.cointracker.entity.Wallet;
import java.util.Optional;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2021-01-25T19:41:00+0300",
    comments = "version: 1.4.1.Final, compiler: javac, environment: Java 1.8.0_261 (Oracle Corporation)"
)
@Component
public class WalletMapperImpl implements WalletMapper {

    @Override
    public WalletResponse walletToWalletResponse(Optional<Wallet> wallet) {
        if ( wallet == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        WalletResponse walletResponse = new WalletResponse();

        return walletResponse;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the generated sources of MapStruct under `target\generated-sources\annotations`

Regarding this github issue https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/674 using Optional is currently not supported. In the issue you'll find a workaround code example.

Comment: When I use `Wallet` instead of `Optional<Wallet>` everything works as I expected.Thanks for pointing out, I'll look in more detail tomorrow to see what issue in mapstruct suggests.

Comment: As the generated code shows: MapStruct is currently not able to handle Optional types. What you could do is call mapping ifPresent or else return null. This would of cause move the check one layer up but would resolve your problem.